# $.post not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have some script like this:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
 alert("before");
    $.post("doAction.aspx?id=hotel", {},
         function (response) {

             });
           alert("after");
       return false;
       });
```

the `$.post` is not firing. I really don't know what the error is. I used the same script elsewhere and it worked fine. pls help out.

Comment: you're missing a `;` at the end.

Comment: Change the last line by  `});`

Comment: And have a look into the network tab of Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to see, if the resource even loads. Maybe there is a 404.

Comment: @kylex. **Doesn't matter!** `;` in end of line in `javascript` is optional.

Comment: the statement actually ended with });

Comment: @Wale-Are you using master pages?

Comment: @ Coder no. I'm actually using a `<span id="button">Save</span>` It did work on an application I did before now.

Comment: @PhilipFourie. Why not only buttons have the onclick event...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the alert("before") is firing and you don't have any JS errors in your development console in the browser then the $.post is also firing. I would expect that you get an error response and since you haven't provided a handler ($.post doesn't allow you to do that) then it will simply be consumed and disregarded. Try changing to

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"doAction.aspx?id=hotel",
            data:{},
            success:function(data){...},
            error:function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr); //could be alert if you don't use the dev tools
            },
            dataType:"json"
        });
```

I'd believe you get into the error handler then

Comment: @wale you pass it the same way as post does internally which is you pass it as the data property. If that does not make sense to you write an example of how you would do it with $.post (in your question or in a new question)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this way:

Take an hidden field and store your id value into that and do ajax call like this

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'doAction.aspx?somevalue=' + id,
     data: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) {

      }
   });
```